# access spring model attribute in javascript with variable

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

i added the attribute 'workplaceGroups' to the spring model, which is a list. Later i try to accsess on one object in this list with a given index. But the access only works if i do something like `.get(0)` but i would like to use a variable int to do `.get(i)`but then i get an error.

Can someone tell me why i got this error or how i can use the variable int i?
Thanks for all answers.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    function printTest(i){      


        var test = [[${workplaceGroups.get(0).getId()}]]; //works

        var test2 = [[${workplaceGroups.get(i).getId()}]]; //doesn't work

    }
</script>
```

Comment: `i` is probably not being set

Comment: i is javascript code, thus you can't not pass it into a server side template engine.

Comment: thanks i think you are right. is there another way to do it?

Comment: @Gebil15 you can create a rest call on your server with `@ResponseBody` and then use it when a page loads with ajax as a basic solution to retrieve `workplaceGroups` and then do whatever you want in javascript